# Spring AOP aspect does not intercept annotated method

Tags: java, spring, aspectj, spring-aop

i want to use the `@before` ,`@after` and `@AfterThrowing` in my function.
If other function use the annotation like `@MyAspectTest`, it should run `beforeAction()`, `afterAction()` and `afterExcept()` at related time.
But, it seems doesn't work.

i have already input the dependency and modified the beans.

```java
package com.service.metrics;

import com.mgr.CMPMgr;
import org.aspectj.lang.JoinPoint;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.After;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Aspect;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Before;

import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.AfterThrowing;

import java.lang.reflect.Method;

@Aspect
public class CMPAspect {
    @Before(value="@annotation(com.mgr.CMPMgr)")
    public void beforeAction(JoinPoint joinPoint) throws ClassNotFoundException {
      testcode
    }

    @After(value="@annotation(com.mgr.CMPMgr)")
    public void afterAction(){
      testcode
    }

    @AfterThrowing(value="@annotation(com.mgr.CMPMgr)")
    public void afterExcept(){
      testcode
    }
}
```

```java
package com.mgr;

public @interface CMPMgr {
    String name() default "";
    long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
}
```

```java
    @CMPMgr(name = "vipGet")
    @GET
    @Produces({ MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON, MediaType.APPLICATION_XML })
    @Path("/{lbId}")
    public Response get(@PathParam("lbId")String lbId,
                        @HeaderParam("Authorization") String basicAuthData,
                        @HeaderParam("UserID") String behalf) {
```

```xml
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
            <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
            <version>1.8.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
            <artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>
            <version>1.8.0</version>
        </dependency>
```

```xml
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:jpa="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa" xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
       xmlns:task="http://www.springframework.org/schema/task"
       xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa/spring-jpa-1.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context  http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-4.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/task http://www.springframework.org/schema/task/spring-task-4.2.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.0.xsd">
    <aop:aspectj-autoproxy />
    <!-- enabling annotation driven configuration / -->
    <context:annotation-config />
    <context:component-scan />

    <!-- responsible for registering the necessary Spring components that power
        annotation-driven transaction management; such as when @Transactional methods
        are invoked -->
    <tx:annotation-driven />
```

it should get into the Aspect functions. But i don't find it work in debug mode. Why?

Comment: You need either to provide method for after/before or at least wildcard it.

Comment: Your sample code is incomplete. Please be advised to learn about [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and write/edit your questions accordingly. Otherwise I have to make educated guesses like I did in my answer, which is suboptimal because maybe it helps you, maybe not.

Answer (score 3):

Some things come to mind:

- Your annotation needs runtime retention, but I do not see `@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)` in your code.
- Your aspect should be a `@Component`, but I do not see the corresponding annotation either.
- The target class containing method `public Response get(..)` also has to be a Spring bean/component. Because you only show incoherent snippets instead of full class definitions, I have no idea which package that class resides in, if it is a Spring component and whether or not it is picked up by component scan.

Comment: Thx for ur feedback! 
I add the Component and @Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME).
It works now.
I need to google the details~

Comment: Google is not necessary, the [Spring AOP manual](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/core.html#aop) will do. Oh, and by the way, please click the grey checkmark beside my answer in order to accept it, it will turn to green then.